# What's the typedef syntax for an array type?

Tags: c++, typedef

I have this C++11 code:

```
using swallow = int[];
```

but MSVS2013 Preview barfs on it:

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '='

So I tried

```
typedef int[] swallow;
```

But that got me:

> warning C4091: 'typedef ' : ignored on left of 'int' when no variable is declared

So I tried reversing the `typedef` stuff, as I never remember (hence the reason `using` is so great):

```
typedef swallow int[];
```

And got:

> m:\development\source\ambrosia\libambrosia\Ambrosia/utility.h++(33) : error C2144: syntax error : 'int' should be preceded by ';'

I'm already disappointed in MSVS2013. How can I write this so the MS compiler will understand this simple code?

Comment: `typedef int swallow[];`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`typdef` is a *declaration*, and follows the same syntax as a declaration:

```
extern int a[];

typedef int b[];
```

(Note that `b` is an incomplete type, and that `a` is only declared, not defined.)